# Draw a polygon with specified edge length in QGIS Madeira

Tags: polygon-creation

I am looking for a possibiliy to draw a polygon with specified edge length in QGIS Madeira. I already checked further Threads belonging to this question, but all answers refer to PlugIns which are not correspondig with the current GIS Version.

Comment: I think that you should specify what you mean by "with specified edge length"...

Comment: If you enable the tools **Advanced Digitizing** and check the icon with the triangle and ruler, a new panel should appear which tells you the distance, angle, x and y coordinate of the edge you are drawing.

Comment: I want to create a rectangle polygon with 200*2m. I already tested the Advanced Digitizing Function but it did not worked properly. When I measure the drawn polygon afterwards I receive different results. With the help of the Advanced Digitzing tool I draw a rectangle with a 200m edge. When I measure it afterwards with the measuring lines tool I only got about 130m.

Comment: Use the measuring tool to trace out where you want your polygon edges. Don't close the measuring tool, so that the orange measurement line remains on the map. Digitize your polygon directly on top of the measurement line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly

1) Create a center point;

2) Run the

Data Analysis>Vector geometry> Rectangles, ovals, rhombuses (fixed),

see figure 1.

[image]
 If you are working in a flat rectangular coordinate system, set the dimensions in meters, if in degrees in the above values, i.e. 1 g = 111 200 m or 0.001 = 111.12 m;

In the test example, I set the values ​​in the above meters 111.2 x 22 meters (in length and width), You can also create the rotation you want, etc.

see Figure 2
[image]