# How to make a rectangle of an exact size/aspect ratio in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector

Is there any way in QGIS to make a vector layer with a rectangle of an exact size or aspect ratio? Ideally, it would be nice if the rectangle from extent tool could be limited to a set aspect ratio, but barring that, is there any way to adjust the size of a vector rectangle directly?

[EDIT]
This is for QGIS 3.4

Comment: which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: Related > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240184/quick-way-to-create-rectangle-by-entering-width-height-numericaly-in-qgis

Comment: Perhaps this answer will suit you ...  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312725/draw-a-polygon-with-specified-edge-length-in-qgis-madeira/312810#312810

Answer (score 3):

**Create grid** can be used to create single polygon. You just need to set xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax to match with horizontal/vertical spacing.

Aspect ratio has to be calculated manually, but it won't be difficult.

[image]